# Switching to FlatUIKit segmented control in runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, flat

I have a `UISegmentedControl` set through a storyboard and I have an outlet for it. In runtime, I have a method which checks if the operating system is less than iOS7 and if it is I need to replace the `UISegmentedControl` to a segmented control from the FlatUIKit. The class is called `FUISegmentedControl` and it inherits from `UISegmentedControl`. Here is it's initialize method:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [FUISegmentedControl class]) {
        FUISegmentedControl *appearance = [self appearance];
        [appearance setCornerRadius:5.0f];
        [appearance setSelectedColor:[AppereanceConfiguration defaultTintColor]];
        [appearance setDeselectedColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [appearance setDividerColor:[AppereanceConfiguration defaultTintColor]];
        [appearance setSelectedFont:[AppereanceConfiguration fontLightWithSize:16]];
        [appearance setDeselectedFont:[AppereanceConfiguration fontLightWithSize:16]];
        [appearance setSelectedFontColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [appearance setDeselectedFontColor:[AppereanceConfiguration defaultTintColor]];
    }
}
```

I don't know how to replace the `UISegmentedControl` with this `FUISegmentedControl` at runtime.

Here is a GitHub link to the FlatUIKit:
[FlatUIKit](https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit)

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Try to add more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted this issue with code instead of storyboard.

I check if IOS <7 with this:

```
#define IS_IOS7 ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >=7)
```

And I added my controls programatically rather than with storyboard.

```
if (IS_IOS7)
{
    self.segmCntr = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
}
else
{
    self.segmCntr = [[FUISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
}
```

Comment: How should I init the FUISegmentedControl?
FUISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[FUISegmentedControl alloc]init]; ?

Comment: what type should self.segmCntr be?

Comment: It should be UISegmentedControl type.

Comment: This way, I can't edit the properties which are from FUISegmentedControl

Comment: I don't know what do you exactly want to do. You can create object like that: if IOS7 UISegmentedControl *segmCntr = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame...] else FUISegmentedControl *flatSegmCntr = [[FUISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame...] and you can set up tag to identify it base on this property.